# Sns boxplot ValueError Length of passed values

Tags: numpy, boxplot

length of data is 295569 how should i arrange?

sns.boxplot(x = data["price"], y = np.arange(500,1000000,25000))

ValueError: Length of passed values is 40, index implies 295569.

Answer (score 0):

```
sns.boxplot(x = data["price"], y = series_x)
```

You could try above code.